# How to specify a less than today condition on a date in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to pull all the records in my set where their fields `publish` is true and `expires` is less than today. I have the following but I don't think the less than part is working, can someone please point me on the right track?

```ruby
Announcement.where(publish: true, :expires < Date.today)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
Announcement.where("publish = ? AND expires < ?", true, Date.today)
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed my record problem, but caused an issue when I tried to call the list in a view. Is this anything to do with the statement, or the way I am creating this filter in the controller?

Comment: QLite3::SQLException: no such column: true: SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" WHERE (publish = true AND expires < '2011-12-10')
Extracted source (around line #25):

22:    <div class="clear"></div>
23: 
24:      <ul id="announcements" class="list-type-1">
25:        <% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
26:          <li>
27:            <%= link_to announcement.headline, announcement_path(announcement) %>
28:          </li>

Comment: I'm no SQL-guru, so I suggest you do it like this instead `@announcements = Announcement.where("publish = ? AND expires < ?", true, Date.today)`

Comment: I'd rather go with:

@announcements = Announcement.where(publish: true).where("expires < ?", Date.today)

I just like hash key values more I guess :-)

Comment: Thanks @calasyr - Very helpful knowing that chaining `.where` results in an "AND"

Answer (score 34):

Since this comes up first on google I thought I'd chime in.  It's probably better to rely on Arel in this circumstance.

```
expires = Announcement.arel_table[:expires]
@announcements = Announcement.where(:publish => true)
  .where(expires.lt(Date.today))
```

That will build the following SQL query

```
-- Using Arel
SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" 
WHERE "announcements"."publish" = 't' 
  AND ("announcements"."expires" < '2016-02-03 18:41:26.454325')

-- Contrast that with the string binding method mentioned above
SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements"
WHERE (publish = 't' AND expires < '2016-02-03 18:41:26.454325')
```

The column names are fully qualified, so you will avoid conflicts when composing other queries on top of this ActiveRecord::Relation i.e `@announcements`

Comment: This is awesome, I've been wondering how to do this elegantly for some time.

Comment: And I guess `arel_table[:expires]` could be a class method `expires_column` on Announcement, so you could `.where(Announcement.expires_column.lt(Date.today))`. It would make it a bit more reusable, perhaps.

Comment: agreed. I recommend this gem https://github.com/camertron/arel-helpers.  Rather than generating methods, you access them like a hash which reads very nice e.g. `Announcement[:expires]`.  Also highly recommend fiddling with www.scuttle.io

Comment: @wycleffsean you're my hero.

Answer (score 7):

Posting this a few years after the other answers, but this is the cleanest approach IMO:

```
Announcement.where(publish: true, expires: ...Date.today)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would to using interval for this.
Your date/time can be limited by interval of dates/times:

```rb
time_from = Time.current - 5.years
time_to = Time.current - 1.year
```

```rb
adult_citties = ::Cat.where(date_birthday: time_from..time_to)
```

When you not need to limit bottom or upper border, you an omit its values:

```rb
old_kitties = ::Cat.where(date_birthday: nil..time_to)
young_kitties = ::Cat.where(date_birthday: time_from..nil)
```

UPD:
also you can omit `nil` too:

```rb
old_kitties = ::Cat.where(date_birthday: ..time_to)
young_kitties = ::Cat.where(date_birthday: time_from..)
```